# How do I pass argument to a scheduled cron task, in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, cron, cron-task

I've set up a cron job to decrement the IntegerField of all objects, every minute.

But it throws the error:

```
TypeError: decrement_days_till_study() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Card'
```

But I have no idea how I might pass this.

cron.py

```
from . models import Card
    
def decrement_days_till_study(Card):
    for card in Card.objects.all():
        if card > 1:
            card.days_till_study -= 10
            card.save()
```

My models are in the same folder as a cron.py.

My settings

```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django_crontab'
]

    CRONJOBS = [
    ('*/1 * * * *', 'spaced_repitition.cron.decrement_days_till_study')]
```

I tested cron by having it print a string which worked fine.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a django expert here, but seems that You are overwriting Your import by defining function variable.

Try removing `Card` from function argument list:

```
from . models import Card

def decrement_days_till_study():
    for card in Card.objects.all():
        if card > 1:
            card.days_till_study -= 10
            card.save()
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!